# Why does apache vhost listen to IP

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Why does a vhost listen directly to an IP?

When requesting an IP address `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` apache returns a webpage meant to be returned when requesting the domain? This will result in duplicate content

Have multiple servers and only this one returns a default vhost when requesting the IP

This is how the vhost looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve it/where the misconfiguration is located?

If all vhosts is deleted, then `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` returns 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put another virtual host before the one with the domain you want.  The first virtual host will be the default one and will be served up if there is not a closer match.  So if you request by the ip then it will match the default one.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to do this.. Have multiple servere and this is the only one which return the first vhost when requesting the IP alone

Comment: The vhosts in the httpd.conf are first so you may have one in there.  then they go in order of filename the ones in conf.d.  Generally I don't put my vhosts in the httpd.conf and then make a vhost file named AAdefault.conf that I know will be the first one.  I point that one at an empty directory so that things like spam bots probing the ip will get nothing.  Doing that may have an impact on search engines so you would need to look at your case to see it works.

Comment: On further thought I am not sure that the ones in the httpd.conf come first.  I uses the first one as its default but if the ones included from the conf.d are included before it may not.  You would have to try it and see.  I don't put vhosts in the main conf file so it has not been an issue for me.